# http status code is displayed as 200 even if my webserver is not running

Tags: http-status-code-200

Even if my webserver is not running, I get the status code 200. Not sure what am i missing?

```
# Check URL

status_line=`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://ipaddress:80" -o /dev/null`
status_code=`echo $status_line | awk '{print $0}'`
echo "STATUS_CODE: ${status_code}"
case "$status_code" in
    200) echo 'Success!'
         ;;
      *) echo 'Fail!'
         exit 1
         ;;
esac
```

Comment: What is the actual output of curl before you parse it? Are you SURE curl is the one generating the 200 and not a bad AWK parse?  And what is the `-sL` parameter? It is not documented on the [curl manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: Even if I run "curl -I http://localhost:80" HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 03 Sep 2014 17:32:30 GMT

Comment: curl does not make responses out of nothing. SOMETHING is responding. Maybe YOUR server is not running, but SOMEONE ELSE's server is.  Maybe an antivirus or proxy/tunnel or something. Use `netstat` or similar tool to find out what app is actually listening on `localhost:80`.